# Can a web browser app be created with Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to create a web browser app similar to (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cake-web-browser/id1163553130?mt=8) using Ionic?

I have the following code but I get this error..

“Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.”

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options

Answer (score 0):

You can get some browser funcionalities with the [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)
or [cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller) in iOS.

Check how the plugin works, maybe you need to fork it to add your own features.